# PHP: Make first letter capital in list?

Tags: php, arrays, string

As i have this:

```
$full_name = $data['full_name'];
list($firstname, $lastname) = explode(' ', $_POST['full_name']);
```

(after this comes a query where it inserts `$lastname` and `$firstname`)

Where should i use `ucfirst()` ?

Should i just make new variables again?

```
$newfirstname = ucfirst($firstname);
$newlastname = ucfirst($lastname);
```

or can i integrate ucfirst somehow somewhere in the code at top?

Comment: Limit explode to return only two elements, ie. `explode(' ', $_POST['full_name'], 2);` But since you can't distinguish between 'Maria Helene Smith' and 'Maria Van Smith' with this scheme, it's better to ask the names separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list($firstName, $lastName) = array_map('ucfirst', explode(' ', $_POST['full_name']));
```

[`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) will apply the function to all array elements.

Answer (score 2):

If they are proper names you could simply use the ucwords() function on the string.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using something like

```
$full_name = ucwords(strtolower($_POST['full_name']));
```

your approach

```
list($firstname, $lastname) = explode(' ', $_POST['full_name']);
```

doesn't work for names containing more than one space.